# insert a new row in the existing column based on conditions in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Sample df

```
| count |   A  |  
|-------|------|
| yes   |  NaN | 
| yes   |  NaN  | 
| yes   |  40  |
| yes   |  40  |
| yes   |  40  |
| yes   |  23  |
```

result I want -> insert 'result' at the end of similar A values

```
| count |   A  |  
|-------|------|
| yes   |  NaN  | 
| yes   |  NaN  | 
| result|      |
| yes   |  40  |
| yes   |  40  |
| yes   |  40  |
| result|      |
| yes   |  23  |
| rseult|      |
```

Comment: Do you want to have the result in the same dataframe, or can it also be a new dataframe with the result for all of the values in A? And what should your result represent? Looks like a case for groupby

Comment: to have the result in the same df - my result would be
add a new row 'result' in column 'count'  after every similar values of column A 
we have to group the nan values also

Comment: Do I understand that right that you want to count the similiar values, so in your example the first `result`row would have an entry in a new colum `count` with 2 (for 2 nans) the next one 3 (for 3 40s) and the last one 1 (for one 23)

Comment: yes  you got it right @FlorianD.

Comment: Maybe still consider going for `groupby.count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to keep order, have chosen to used `fillna()` instead of `dropna=False` to `groupby()`
- simple `append()` to each group

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""count   A
yes NaN
yes NaN
yes 40
yes 40
yes 40
yes 23"""),sep="\t")

df = (df.fillna(-100)
 .groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(lambda dfa: dfa.append({"count":"result"}, ignore_index=True))
 .replace({-100:np.nan})
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Result:

```
|    | count   |   A |
|---:|:--------|----:|
|  0 | yes     | nan |
|  1 | yes     | nan |
|  2 | result  | nan |
|  3 | yes     |  23 |
|  4 | result  | nan |
|  5 | yes     |  40 |
|  6 | yes     |  40 |
|  7 | yes     |  40 |
|  8 | result  | nan |
```

Comment: there are two rows with `NaN` in the input,  the 2 rows in output with appended result row